# dspic33ev Doesn't work after changing pin number

Tags: firmware, dspic

### Description of the situation

The pin number was changed in the code during the existing development and changed using the MCC.

The device does not work after the change.

As shown in the picture below, according to the description of the Micro Chip, main.c is not generated when using MCC in the existing developed code. In my code, all the code is generated again.

I used a third party board and there is no port for debugging.

[image]

### My Computer Setting

> OS : Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
>
> IDE : MPLAB X IDE v5.30
>
> Plugins : MPLAB@ Code Configurator 3.x
>
> Dugger Tool : PICKIT 3

### Question

I have two questions.

1. Is there an option to check if the option is existing development code? Did not find when found.
2. The existing IDE is 5.25, but the development IDE has been upgraded to 5.30. Is there a difference?

### Resources

MPLAB® Code Configurator (MCC) : https://microchipdeveloper.com/mplabx:mcc

PICkit™ 3 In-Circuit Debugger : https://www.microchip.com/Developmenttools/ProductDetails/PG164130

dsPIC33EV 5V CAN-LIN STARTER KIT : https://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails/dm330018

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When code changes using MCC, main.c file is newly created and  main.c  is added to Configurations.c file.

It works if you delete  main.c .

[image]